# How can i add multiple column names in pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns

I have a data set of 256 columns and i want to add column names such as : ['N1', 'N2' ... 'N256']. Is there a quick way to do it ?

I have tried something like that :

```
df.columns = ['S' for x in range(1,257)]
```

But this code just adds the S in every column. How can i add the indexes also ?

Comment: `df.columns = [f'N{i} for i in range(1, 257)]`

Comment: df.add_prefix('N')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this:

```
df.columns = ['N'+str(x) for x in range(1,257)]
```